# PHP checkboxes to retrieve data

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Given a MYSQL database where I have a table containing lots of entries structured as follows:

string  |  type

The field "type" can have 4 values (a, b, c, d) in the database.

I would like to use a checkbox form to retrieve all the string(s) from the database by checking one of the four possible values.

All I have so far is this piece of PHP code:

```
<?
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","****") or die("No DB to select.");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("exercises");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE type = '".$_POST["type"]."'";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
?>

<?
$checkbox = array();

if (isset($_POST["type"])){
 $checked = $_POST["type"];

foreach ($checked as $value) {
    echo "$value"."</br>";
}
}
else{
    echo "Please select at least one type.";
    }
?>
```

The problem is that this code returns only the type values a, b, c, d and not the strings of the entries in the database.

Can anybody out there tell me how to actually access my database entries and retrieve the string value which corresponds to the checked type in the form?
Thanks!

PS: Here is the HTML with the form I'm trying to use:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>select</title>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=latin-1">
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#F5FAE6">
<center>
<h2><p align="center">Make your test</p></h2>
</center>

<br><br>

<form action="output.php" method="POST">
&#10004;&nbsp;Select the <b>type(s) of exercise</b> you need:<br /><br />

<table border="1" cellpadding='4' cellspacing='4' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#9999DD'>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="abc"/> multiple choice</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="error"/> mistake correction</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="cloze"/> cloze</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="makeq"/> make a question</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="trans"/> translate (IT-->EN)</td></tr>
</table>

<p align="center">
<input type="submit" name= "get" value="get your entries!"/>
</p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the connection to database etc?

Comment: Where is your database connection / query code?

Comment: Do you even have a sql query? Please show use what sql query you have attempted so far or as the first two comments suggest, show use your connection

Comment: Well, I've edited my post to include the connection to my database... but as you can see I have no clue how to access the entries in it.

Comment: The name of string field is "text".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are echoing the types not the results returned from mysql query..

Your code *should read*:

```
if (isset($_POST["type"])){
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
    echo $row['text']."<br />";  
}
else{
    echo "Please select at least one type.";
}
```

Comment: What's the error? can you confirm whether `$_POST['type']` contains any values?

Comment: Are you saying your form method is GET and not POST? Seems the problem is from your form.

Comment: If I remove the WHERE condition, the PHP code returns all the entries in my database, but I'd like it to return only those which have the "type" I checked in the form.

Comment: Can you do a `die(var_export($_POST));` on your php. What does it show?

Comment: That means nothing was selected then

Comment: If I remove the [] it returns only the entries of 1 checkbox. I need to be able to check more than one.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, put it back. And access it the way you were accessing it before, I think the values were not sent previously

Comment: I've restored the []. I still think the problem is in the query. But I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do this

```
    <php
      if (isset($_POST["type"]))
      {
        $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","****") or die("No DB found");
        $objDB = mysql_select_db("exercises");
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE type IN(";
         foreach($_POST['type'] as $t)
         {
            $strSQL .="'".$t."',";
         }
         $strSQL=rtrim($strSQL,",").")";
         $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
         while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) 
         {
         echo $row['type']."<br>";
         }
        mysql_close($objConnect);
       }
    else{
        echo "Please select at least one type.";
       }
     ?>
```